# how to do this so it does show "No Value" instead of getting caught in an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I am using the following code which works fine as long as I dont have one of the child node (e.g. URL) missing. If it
is missing then my code errors out. How can I make it to not error out and just return a string "No Value" instead.

here is my code

```
string widgetsInfo = 
    loaded.Descendants("widget")
          .Select((w, i) =>
                new
                    {
                        WidgetIndex = i,
                        URL = w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        Category = w.Descendants("PortalCategoryId").FirstOrDefault().Value
                    })
            .Select(w => String.Format("Index:{0}; URL:{1}; CATEGORY:{2}; ",
                                        w.WidgetIndex, w.URL, w.Category))
            .Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + Environment.NewLine + next);
```

here is the xml that I am parsing

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<widgets>
    <widget>
        <url>~/Portal/Widgets/ServicesList.ascx</url>
        <castAs>ServicesWidget</castAs>
        <urlType>ascx</urlType>
        <parameters>
            <PortalCategoryId>3</PortalCategoryId>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
    <widget>
        <url>www.omegacoder.com</url>
        <castAs>ServicesWidget</castAs>
        <urlType>htm</urlType>
        <parameters>
            <PortalCategoryId>41</PortalCategoryId>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   string widgetsInfo = 
    loaded.Descendants("widget")
          .Select((w, i) =>
                new
                    {
                        WidgetIndex = i,
                        URL = w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault() == null ? "No Value" : w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        Category = w.Descendants("PortalCategoryId").FirstOrDefault() == null ? "No Value" : w.Descendants("PortalCategoryId").FirstOrDefault().Value
                    })
            .Select(w => String.Format("Index:{0}; URL:{1}; CATEGORY:{2}; ",
                                        w.WidgetIndex, w.URL, w.Category))
            .Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + Environment.NewLine + next);
```

Comment: @user400749 Which node? The Category? Just repeat the same logic I used for "url". See my edit.

Comment: no it doesnt work for any...if the node is missing it will throw error...category or url

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) linq clause.